# Find the maximum distance between two pairwise given elements

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

This code is  designed to find the minimum distance between two elements.As example below the minimum distance between 3 and 3 should return 5 but I need 
the furthest one not the nearest one, what I should to find the maximum distance between no 3 and no 3?

```
   internal class MinimumDistance
{
    internal virtual int minDist(int[] arr, int n, int x, int y)
    {
        int i, j;
        int min_dist = int.MaxValue;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            {
                if ((x == arr[i] && y == arr[j] || y == arr[i] && x == arr[j]) && min_dist > Math.Abs(i - j))
                {
                    min_dist = Math.Abs(i - j);
                }
            }
        }
        return min_dist;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MinimumDistance min = new MinimumDistance();
        int[] arr = new int[] { 3, 2, 4, 2, 6, 5, 3, 6, 5, 4, 8, 3 };
        int n = arr.Length;
        int x = 3;
        int y = 3;

        Console.WriteLine("Minimum distance between " + x + " and " + y + " is " + min.minDist(arr, n, x, y)); //return the nearest 3 so it will be 5
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `min_dist` to `int.MinValue`, and substitute a less than sign in `min_dist > Math.Abs(i - j)`, and then rename the variable (and method).

Comment: Oh, Thanks it works perfectly.

Comment: Notice that you can do it faster than your O(n^2) method

Answer (score 0):

This code should do:

```
internal class MaximumDistance
{
    internal virtual int maxDist(int[] arr, int n, int x, int y)
    {
        var max_dist = int.MinValue;
        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (var j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
                if ((x == arr[i] && y == arr[j] || y == arr[i] && x == arr[j]) && max_dist < Math.Abs(i - j))
                    max_dist = Math.Abs(i - j);
        return max_dist;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var max = new MaximumDistance();
        var arr = new int[] { 3, 2, 4, 2, 6, 5, 3, 6, 5, 4, 8, 3 };
        var n = arr.Length;
        var x = 3;
        var y = 3;

        Console.WriteLine("Maximum distance between " + x + " and " + y + " is " + max.maxDist(arr, n, x, y));
    }
}
```